# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2008 sspi

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sspi

I have a SQL server running on a machine in my local network. I have been connecting to it via Windows authentication for the past 3 months. There is only 1 other user (the Sa) and he has been able to connect for the past year or 2, no problems.

Now this week we both get an SSPI error and neither of us can connect. We can't remember the `sa` login, as we both have been using Windows authentication.

I can login fine to Windows authentication, rebooted my machine but still cant access server. We get the same error, sspi.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the Windows Event Logs for error messages.

Comment: Is the machine still running?  Perhaps a firewall was turned on?

Comment: Check the database service is up and running in services.msc

Comment: Start here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811889 Then see these other answers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22cannot+generate+sspi+context%22&submit=search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bah, the SA changed his password. Needed to restart server, login with new password. Thanks guys for the tips